Как открыть маркеры при клике на поинт Я.Карты?
У меня есть скрипт, который добавляет на страницу карты. В карте добавляет маркеры и кластеризует их (объединяет маркеры в один поинт см.скрин)
Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на поинт открывались маркеры? В версии 2.1 это решалось при помощи .setBounds, как я понял
Но сейчас это не работает. Не могу найти решения моего вопроса в доке. Может кто проходил такое?
Сам код:
    window.map = null;

    // Основная функция
    async function main() {
        // Ожидаем загрузку API Яндекс.Карт
        await ymaps3.ready;

        // Импортируем необходимые компоненты из API
        const {YMap, YMapDefaultSchemeLayer, YMapMarker, YMapLayer, YMapFeatureDataSource} = ymaps3;
        const {YMapClusterer, clusterByGrid} = await ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-clusterer@0.0.1');

        // Инициализируем карту
        map = new YMap(
            // Передаем ссылку на HTML-элемент контейнера карты
            document.getElementById('map'),
            // Передаем параметры инициализации карты
            {
                location: {
                    // Устанавливаем координаты центра карты и масштаб
                    center: [37.588144, 55.733842],
                    zoom: 6
                },
            }
        );

        // Добавляем слои для отображения схемы и маркеров
        map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer());
        map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer());
        map.addChild(new YMapFeatureDataSource({id: 'my-source'}));
        map.addChild(new YMapLayer({source: 'my-source', type: 'markers', zIndex: 1800}));

        // Создаем содержимое маркера
        const contentPin = document.createElement('div');
        contentPin.className = 'map__marker';

        // Создаем функцию для создания маркера
        const marker = (feature) =>
            new ymaps3.YMapMarker(
                {
                    coordinates: feature.geometry.coordinates,
                    source: 'my-source',
                },
                contentPin.cloneNode(true),
            );

        // Создаем функцию для создания кластера
        const cluster = (coordinates, features) =>
            new ymaps3.YMapMarker(
                {
                    coordinates,
                    source: 'my-source'
                },
                circle(features.length).cloneNode(true)
            );

        // Создаем функцию для создания кругов кластера
        function circle(count) {
            // Создаем пустой див и присваиваем ему класс
            const circle = document.createElement('div');
            circle.classList.add('map__circles');

            // Заполняем содержимое дива
            circle.innerHTML = `
                <div class="map__circles-content circle-content">
                    <span class="map__circles-count">${count}</span>
                </div>
            `;
            return circle;
        }

        // Получаем все элементы с классом 'map-coordinates' из документа
        const coordinatesInHtml = document.querySelectorAll('.map-coordinates');
        const coordinates = [];

        // Для каждой координаты
        coordinatesInHtml.forEach(el => {
            // Получаем значения координат из списка магазинов
            const dataCoordinates = el.getAttribute('data-coordinates').split(',').map(parseFloat);

            // Меняем порядок координат, так как в Яндекс.Картах порядок широты и долготы отличается
            //¯\_(ツ)_/¯
            const location = [dataCoordinates[1], dataCoordinates[0]];

            // Добавляем координаты в массив
            coordinates.push(location);
        });

        // Создаем массив точек для кластеризации
        const points = coordinates.map((lnglat, i) => ({
            type: 'Feature',
            id: i,
            geometry: {coordinates: lnglat},
            properties: {name: 'Point of issue of orders'}
        }));

        // Создаем кластеризатор
        const clusterer = new YMapClusterer({
            // Указываем метод кластеризации и размер сетки
            method: clusterByGrid({gridSize: 64}),
            // Передаем точки для кластеризации, функции создания маркера и функции создания кластера
            features: points,
            marker,
            cluster
        });

        // Добавляем кластеризатор на карту
        map.addChild(clusterer);
    }

    // Вызываем основную функцию
    main();```


В JS API 3.0 кластер реализован так, что он не содержит меток и сам является скорее меткой, чем коллекцией геообъектов, соответственно, напрямую получить объекты в кластере не получится.
Вы можете конфигурировать маркер кластера и его поведение свойством cluster. В это свойство вы можете добавить любой обработчик onClick. Свойства маркеров вы можете посмотреть в Документации.
